# Is Rooting possible for Xperia t3?

Tags: rooting, sony-xperia

Please help me in rooting my phone xperia t3. The ram is very less and there are so many unwanted apps. How to remove them?

Comment: Have you tried the answer below, and if yes, how did it go? If it worked, perhaps you might like to "Accept" the answer and/or share your experience for the benefit of other users???

Comment: i was not sure about the ways to root. so I did not risked .

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible, I found this method among many others.

**Warnings:**

Below are some warning statements that you should be aware of, before proceeding with the rooting tutorial:

```
Rooting your Sony Xperia T3 Android Smartphone will void its warranty. 
Hence, to get back warranty after rooting your Sony Xperia T3, you will 
have to flash the stock ROM back again.

Take a complete backup of all the data stored on your Sony Xperia T3, 
as the rooting process will wipe away all the data stored on your Smartphone.
There are risks of your Sony Xperia T3 getting damaged, if the rooting guide below 
is not followed properly. Hence, proceed at your own risk only and we are
not to be blamed in any such case scenarios.
```

**Prerequisites:**

Here are a few prerequisite procedures to complete prior to rooting Sony Xperia T3 Android Smartphone:

```
Download and install the latest USB Drivers for Sony Xperia T3 on your PC.
Charge your Sony Xperia T3 until it has a minimum battery backup of 80%.
Download the root tool from here.
Enable USB Debugging on your Smartphone.
```

**Root Sony Xperia T3 Easily Using One-Click Method:**

Below is the detailed guide on how to root Sony Xperia T3 Android Smartphone easily using the one-click root method:

```
Connect your Sony Xperia T3 to the PC.
Copy/Paste the root tool that you downloaded earlier to your Smartphone.
Disconnect your Smartphone from the PC.
Now, navigate to the copied file using file explorer, and click on the copied file once.
This will begin the process to install the root tool on your Sony Xperia T3.
After installation, launch the app from your Smartphone.
Follow the on screen instructions and when prompted to choose 
an EXPLOIT, choose the “GANDALF” exploit.
Wait for the rooting process to complete.
Reboot your Sony Xperia T3.
```

Hope this helps.

Source : [Rootandroid](http://rootandroide.com/2014/07/21/root-sony-xperia-t3-easily/)

Comment: FYI, Root Tool download link is missing, and Rootandroid link is broken.